# access hbase in IDE Eclipse , java.net.UnknownHostException while inserting data in hbase

Tags: hbase

I am referring to https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/blob/master/ch03/src/main/java/client/PutExample.java, to write a programs which creates and puts data in Hbase. I am running in a standalone mode.

However, while executing the program, I am getting Unknown Host exception.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: �  13846@yzdlocalhost
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.<init>(HBaseClient.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:954)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:816)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:141)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:295)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:272)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:324)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:579)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
at com.hbasebook.hush.schema.SchemaManager.process(SchemaManager.java:126)
at com.hbasebook.hush.HushMain.main(HushMain.java:57)
```

Does anyone have any idea , what might be causing this issue ? I am not sure from where it is trying to retrieve that host name. Do I have to add it to the host file ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Local hbase version did not match the one I was using as a dependency in my pom file. That fixed it.